# merge/concatenate based on a condition

Tags: bash

I have two files I'm trying to join/merge based on columns 1 and 2.

**input1**

```
22  42960000    rs149201999 A   AC  100 PASS    LDAF=0.0649;RSQ=0.8652;AN=2184;ERATE=0.0046;VT=SNP;AA=.;AVGPOST=0.9799;THETA=0.0149;SNPSOURCE=LOWCOV;AC=134;AF=0.06;ASN_AF=0.04;AMR_AF=0.05;AFR_AF=0.10;EUR_AF=0.06
```

**input2**

```
22  42960000    .   A   AC  .   .    ;AA=1;AFE=0.989691;ASNE=1;EUN=0.992509;AFW=1;MED=0.991071;LAT=1
```

**And output will be**

```
22  42960000    .   A   AC  .   .    ;AA=1;AFE=0.989691;ASNE=1;EUN=0.992509;AFW=1;MED=0.991071;LAT=1;LDAF=0.0649;RSQ=0.8652;AN=2184;ERATE=0.0046;VT=SNP;AA=.;AVGPOST=0.9799;THETA=0.0149;SNPSOURCE=LOWCOV;AC=134;AF=0.06;ASN_AF=0.04;AMR_AF=0.05;AFR_AF=0.10;EUR_AF=0.06
```

note each column is separated by tab.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way using `GNU awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { array[$1,$2]=$8; next } ($1,$2) in array { print $0 ";" array[$1,$2] }' input1 input2
```

Result:

```
22  42960000    .   A   AC  .   .    ;AA=1;AFE=0.989691;ASNE=1;EUN=0.992509;AFW=1;MED=0.991071;LAT=1;LDAF=0.0649;RSQ=0.8652;AN=2184;ERATE=0.0046;VT=SNP;AA=.;AVGPOST=0.9799;THETA=0.0149;SNPSOURCE=LOWCOV;AC=134;AF=0.06;ASN_AF=0.04;AMR_AF=0.05;AFR_AF=0.10;EUR_AF=0.06
```

Comment: Above code is working fine,And the same time I don't want ** AA=.**  from the input1 file on the result output file

Comment: @user1782877: Try: `awk 'FNR==NR { sub(/AA=\.;/,""); array[$1,$2]=$8; next } ... `

Comment: Thanks Steve:) **gzip -dc input1.vcf.gz input2.vcf.gz | awk 'FNR==NR { sub(/AA=\.;/,""); array[$1,$2]=$8; next } ($1,$2) in array { print $0 ";" array[$1,$2] }' | gzip > output.vcf.gz** I tried this command but its not generating the output

Comment: Thanks Steve ...Code working fine now:)

Comment: There is some problem while using with big size file,may be because of the content.So I am planning to append only **VT=**(VT=SV,VT=SNP) and **AF=**(NOT ASN_AF etc)fields to the second file,Then the output is like 22  42960000    .   A   AC  .   .    ;AA=1;AFE=0.989691;ASNE=1;EUN=0.992509;AFW=1;MED=0.991071;LAT=1;VT=SNP;AF=0.06

Comment: @user1782877: Try this: `awk -v OFS=";" 'FNR==NR { split($8, hold, OFS); for (i in hold) { if (hold[i] ~ /^VT=|^AF=/) line = (line ? line OFS : line) hold[i] } array[$1,$2]=line; line=""; next } ($1,$2) in array { print $0, array[$1,$2] }' input1 input2`

Comment: **awk -v OFS=";" 'FNR==NR { split($8, hold, OFS); for (i in hold) { if (hold[i] ~ /^VT=|^AF=/) line = (line ? line OFS : line) hold[i] } array[$1,$2]=line; line=""; next } ($1,$2) in array { print $0, array[$1,$2] }' <(gzip -dc input1.vcf.gz) <(gzip -dc input2.vcf.gz) | gzip >output.vcf.gz** Working fine with Small file.But it Throwing errors like gzip: **input2.vcf.gz: unexpected end of file** while using with big files

Comment: @user1782877: So `gzip` is throwing `EOF`. I'm guessing `input2.vcf.gz` is corrupt. Run `md5sum input2.vcf.gz` on the file you're working with currently and run the same command on the original file from it's download location (I'm assuming you've downloaded it from somewhere). If the codes are different, then the file you're working with is corrupt. Please let me know how this goes.

Comment: 45fc90e227d5f4fce9daf5af31f45948  input2.vcf.gz
 Just got output like this md5sum input2.vcf.gz Now the code is working fine

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
s=%%%%%%
join -j1 -o1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,2.7 <(sed "s/\t/$s/" input2) \
                                           <(sed "s/\t/$s/" input1) \
| sed "s/$s/\t/;
       s/\(=[^ ]*\) \([^ ]*=\)/\1;\2/;
       s/ \+/\t/g"
```